# Get all members of every AD Groups in OU

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm new to Powershell and AD. I've got the challenge of being able to query an OU to retrieve all Groups in that OU and then all members of each group. I've currently got the following script which allows me to do it:

```
$Groups = Get-ADGroup -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=xx,OU=xx xx,DC=xx,DC=xx" -SERVER "xxxxxx" #creates a variable with the name Groups and stores all the groups into it

$Results = foreach( $Group in $Groups ){ #looks for members in each group and stores them in Results
    Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -SERVER "xxxxxx" | Select distinguishedName | foreach {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            GroupName = $Group.Name
            Name = $_
        }
    }
}

$Results| sort -Property GroupName | Export-Csv -Path c:\Temp\groups.csv -NoTypeInformation #stores results in a csv
```

The issue that I've got is I need to be able to do the same but in ***one line*** so that I can run it and pull it back into Excel (for reporting on). I can't execute the script from Excel due to signing but I could execute one line. Any advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: "I can't execute the script from Excel due to signing" - yes you can. Just use `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` on the `powershell.exe` command line.

Comment: @Bill_Stewart Awesome. Wasn't sure how to do this except by doing it in 3 separate lines (Bypass, Call script, Reset). Running it now and it seems to be working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the `EncodedCommand` option:

```
$ScriptText  = Get-Content C:\Path\To\Script.ps1 -Raw
$ScriptBytes = [System.Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes($ScriptText)
$EncCommand  = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String($ScriptBytes)
```

Now copy the contents of `$EncCommand` (with `$EncCommand |Set-ClipBoard` for example) and supply the resulting base64 string as a command line argument to the `EncodedCommand` command line switch:

```
powershell.exe -EncodedCommand JABHAHIAbwB1AHAAcwAgAD0AIABHAGUAdAA...
```